# How to prove or disprove that the derivative at a certain point exists?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Assume that $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, and for all $x \neq 0$, $f'(x)$ exists. Also, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f'(x) = L$ exists. Either prove that $f'(0)$ exists or give a counterexample.

How would I go about solving this problem? I hoped that the statement was false and I tried playing around with counter examples, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: @KevinSheng No, the derivative of $|x|$ doesn't have a limit at $0.$

Comment: The result follows from the MVT.

Comment: I'm in my phone but I hope this works. Write the definition for the limit definition of the derivative at 0 as an average of the limit definition on both sides.

Comment: Ah, yes I did not see that part. My mistake.

Comment: @JohnDouma Thanks; overlooked that...

Answer (score 4):

Here's the (fleshed-out) method in the comments. We want to show that:

$$f'(0) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = L$$

To that end, pick $\varepsilon > 0$. Choose $\delta > 0$ such that, for $0 < |x| < \delta$, $|f'(x) - L| < \varepsilon$. Now, suppose $0 < |h| < \delta$. Our goal will be to show:

$$\left|\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} - L\right| < \varepsilon$$

That will complete the proof. First, assume $h > 0$. The assumptions of the MVT all hold on the interval $[0,h]$, so there exists $0 < c < h$ such that:

$$f'(c) = \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h}$$

Now, since $0 < c < h < \delta$ we have:

$$\left|\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} - L\right| = |f'(c) - L| < \varepsilon$$

We can do the exact same type of argument if $h < 0$: Pick $c$ using the MVT on the interval $[h,0]$, and one has, again:

$$\left|\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} - L\right| = |f'(c) - L| < \varepsilon$$